# Populating properties of an object without overwriting them

Tags: c#

I have defined a `class` with some `public` properties that I can get or set for example

```
public class Employee
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a `LINQ` query that returns me a list of Employees that meet some criteria so each query may return a list of some employees, for example same person can have three phones so I am getting three rows back in the query result.

```
var empRows = LinqQueryToReturnSomeRows();
```

so for example:

```
Hoffman, Mark, BMW, "", ""
Hoffman, Mark, "", "", 56
Hoffman, Mark, Nissan, 7209886985, 78
```

Now what I want to do is being able to have **ONE** row for that person populated with data, **if** the data is already populated from its previous result then **DO NOT overwrite it** so result in example above would be:

```
Hoffman, Mark, BMW, 7209886985, 56
```

What is an algorithm and approach I can do that?

Comment: if each setter in a given property had something like `if property.isEmpty() then set to new value`, would that do it?

Comment: Try looking into PostSharp to add an aspect to all your properties that does the check suggested by @mickey

Comment: I don't have the knowledge about any of the techniques you all mentioned above.

Comment: Can't you just match them up by ID?

Comment: If each `Employee` *can* have three phones, then your data structure does not match up with reality. You need a `List` or some other collection or data structure for that, and also for `Car` too. On the other hand, I would think `ID` should be unique (shown in example of having two values).

Comment: @mickey hmm yeah that's good idea to try. Can you hash out a quick example please? Should I not use Automatic Properties in that case? which is alright, I can do that.

Comment: Agreed, you should have an employee table, a contactDetails table and a car table  (and possibly an employeeCar table if appropriate).  Fix your underlying data structure otherwise you keep running into these issues.

Comment: sorry guys! that's what the client wants it to be! they are importing their data from a text file to DB and that's how they told me to populate it. I know it is weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have a list of `empRows` and it's sorted in order of precedence (or maybe that doesn't matter to you). You could do something very simple like:

```
 Employee e = new Employee();
 foreach (var er in empRows)
 {
    e.LastName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.LastName) ? er.LastName : e.LastName;
    // ...etc for all the other properties
 }
```

The alternative is that you can move the check into the property definition itself so that you have something like:

```
public class Employee
{
    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set 
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastName))
            {
                _lastName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I tend to think this will be a pain to maintain because you basically have a "write-once" property which may not be obvious to somebody else using your code.

If you want to get fancy, you could use the `Aggregate` function to do something like this:

```
var e = empRows.Aggregate(new Employee(), (curr,next) => {
    curr.LastName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(curr.LastName) ? next.LastName : curr.LastName;
    // etc
    return curr;
});
```

Comment: yep I myself also had started writing it with the for-each way...What do you suggest better? the for-each way or the write-one property way?

Comment: @user143502: For the reasons I outlined in my answer, I'm not a fan of the write-once property. I don't think it's very obvious that that is what it does and may come back to bite you when you try and change the value and get no compile time or run time errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
private string _LastName;
public string LastName 
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LastName) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_LastName))
        {
            return "Empty"; // or whatever
        }
        else
        {
            return _LastName;
        }

    }
    set
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LastName) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_LastName))
        {
            _LastName = value;
        }
        // else do not set
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to call both versions of `String.IsNull...`.  `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` acts the same as `Empty` except it also trims.

Comment: I was wondering about this. I wanted to cover all the bases so I erred on the side of caution. Also, @OP, you may not want to do anything the with getter. I have this there because when displaying data from the database directly to a GUI, I don't want a blank space, so I fill it in.

Comment: I'd also check if `_LastName == null || _LastName == "" _LastName == String.Empty`. Both in invariant culture and current culture! **;) LOL**